# A tricky question on sequences of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[
{1 \over x + 1} + {2x \over \left(x + 1\right)\left(x + 2\right)}
+{3x^{2} \over \left(x + 1\right)\left(x + 2\right)\left(x + 3\right)}
+ \cdots
+ {nx^{n-1} \over
\left(x + 1\right)\left(x + 2\right)\ldots\left(x + n\right)}\right]$$

Comment: it should be x^{n-1}

Comment: Can partial fractions help in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

For integer $r\ge1$,

$$\frac{rx^{r-1}}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+r-1)(x+r)}+\frac{x^r}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+r-1)(x+r)}=\frac{x^{r-1}}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+r-1)}$$

$$\iff  \frac{rx^{r-1}}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+r-1)(x+r)}$$
$$=\frac{x^{r-1}}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+r-1)}-\frac{x^r}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+r-1)(x+r)} $$

Set $r=1,2,3,c\dots, n-1,n$ to add to recognize the [Telescoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) Series

Finally set $n\to\infty$

Comment: @Umakant, Welcome. But, what is limit?

Comment: It comes down to $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1 - \frac{x^n}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)} = 1$. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @Umakant, It's true for finite $x$ if $x$ is $O(n^r)$ where $r<1$

Comment: Even if my $x\rightarrow \infty$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$, I guess the above limit will give 1. Or is there some thing else?